# how to change currency variable to number variable (without the sign of the currency) in R software?

Tags: r

i want to use the data without the currency sign, but the sample of data is too much to do in manual. i use this in software R, if anyone knows how to fix this, please reply below

Comment: Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).   R doesn't have a "currency" data type, so please clarify exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I expect `readr::parse_number()` should work here.